# AWS Python CDK - define the launch template for Batch Compute Environment

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, aws-batch

In my Python CDK Stack, I'm trying to configure an AWS Batch Compute Environment to be able to use a `Launch Template` I'm creating in the same stack. Example:

```py
launch_template = ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate(
    scope=self,
    id=f"{stack_id}-EC2LaunchTemplate",
    launch_template_name=f"{stack_id}-EC2LaunchTemplate",
    launch_template_data=ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate.LaunchTemplateDataProperty(
        image_id="ami-xxxxxxxxxxx",
        instance_type="xxxxxxxxxx",
        ebs_optimized=True,
        user_data=Fn.base64(...)
    )
)

compute_env_gpu = batch.ManagedEc2EcsComputeEnvironment(
    scope=self,
    id="compute_env_id",
    ...
    launch_template=launch_template
)
```

My Stack without the launch template works well.
The definition as above passes `cdk synth`, but fails `cdk deploy` with the following error:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Error executing request, Exception : LaunchTemplateId or LaunchTemplateName is required.
```

If instead I use this:

```py
launch_template=batch.CfnComputeEnvironment.LaunchTemplateSpecificationProperty(
    launch_template_name=f"{stack_id}-EC2LaunchTemplate",
)
```

I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Passed to parameter props of new aws-cdk-lib.aws_batch.ManagedEc2EcsComputeEnvironment: Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_batch.ManagedEc2EcsComputeEnvironmentProps
├──  Failing value is an object
│      { '$jsii.struct': [Object] }
╰──  Failure reason(s):
    ╰─ Key 'launchTemplate': Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.ILaunchTemplate | undefined
        ├──  Failing value is an object
        │      { '$jsii.struct': [Object] }
        ╰──  Failure reason(s):
            ╰─ Value does not have the "$jsii.byref" key
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using [ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/CfnLaunchTemplate.html) instead of [ec2.LaunchTemplate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/LaunchTemplate.html)?  In particular the CfnLT object does not have a `launch_template_id` attribute from `ILaunchTemplate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`batch.ManagedEc2EcsComputeEnvironment.launch_template` is expecting `ec2.ILaunchTemplate` interface which `ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate` does not satisfy. Use [`ec2.LaunchTemplate`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/LaunchTemplate.html) instead.